# How to add the topic to spring-boot kafka metrics?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, jmx, spring-boot-actuator

In *dropwizard* the prometheus metrics do include the topic for producers and consumers as label. This is quite essential for monitoring and controlling the load to the specific pods in our cluster.

However the *spring-boot* services do not seem to include the topic as label in the metrics, and I wasn't able to find any solution yet. Is there any way to archive this?

Example dropwizard metrics (stripped down):

```
kafka_producer_record_send_rate{application="my-dropwizard-service", client="my-dropwizard-service-20230925-123734.045_my-dropwizard-service-7d659554b4-lgk7r-StreamThread-1-producer", topic="ip-cds-gateway"} 0
```

Example sprint-boot metrics (stripped down):

```
kafka_producer_record_send_rate{application="my-spring-boot-service", client_id="my-message.my-spring-boot-service-2731f24b-1d88-4120-b62f-558059ea9b59-StreamThread-1-producer", kafka_version="3.1.2", spring_id="defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder"} 0
```

Some versions used:

- spring-boot 2.7.15
- spring-boot-starter-actuator 2.7.15
- spring-kafka 2.8.11
- micrometer-core 1.9.14
- micrometer-rgistry-prometheus 1.9.14

Beside I only register a `MeterRegistryCustomizer` at the application start:

```
    @Bean
    MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
        return registry -> registry.config().commonTags("application", "my-spring-boot-service");
    }
```

Comment: What version of spring-kafka are you using? Perhaps you can look at the source code for the metric creation?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks, I added the versions and some metrics setup to the question

Comment: What happens when you try with 3.x release of spring-kafka / boot? Ultimately, Spring doesn't do anything to the JMX metrics. You can see a list at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html#producer-per-topic-metrics